# How to sort values of tree map grabbed from twitter api and show it in TextView(android)?

Tags: java, android, twitter, treemap, sortedmap

Using twitter 4j library, I grab latest tweet of the user and then grab retweeters id and their followers count. 
Now what i need to do is show the id of retweeeters, sort them in descending order of followers i.e highest follower first rank.
I grabbed and put the followers count in tree map , now how to sort them ? and then show them in TextView ?
Using twitter4j i grabbed tweets of the user and put them in 'status' rest of it is :-

```
//get  the first status
        status = statuses.get(0);
     //get id of the status
          long l= status.getId(); 
        //get retweeters id
          ki =twitter.getRetweeterIds(l, 100, -1);

         long[] id=ki.getIDs();
         //for every retweeter id, get followers count and put in treemap
         TreeMap<Integer,Long> tm = new TreeMap<Integer, Long>();
         for(int k=0;k<=id.length;k++)
         {
             u = twitter.showUser(id[k]);
             follower=u.getFollowersCount();
             tm.put(follower,id[k] );
         }
        NavigableMap<Integer,Long> reverseTreeMap = tm.descendingMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
This is how i did it

```
//Using treemap to sort retweeters according to their followers
 TreeMap<Integer,String> tm = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
 try{
     for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
         {
             publishProgress(5);
             Log.i(a, "treemap followers"+k);
             u = twitter.showUser(id[k]);
             follower=u.getFollowersCount();
             url=u.getProfileImageURL();
             tm.put(follower,url );
         }
    }
catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(a, e.toString());
    }
Log.i(a, "Done treemap");

 //Reverse the order of the treemap 
 Log.i(a, "Reversing Treemap");
 NavigableMap<Integer,String> reverseTreeMap = tm.descendingMap();
 publishProgress(5);

 //Put treemap values in string array
 s=reverseTreeMap.values().toString();
 s=s.replace("[", "");
 s=s.replace("]", "");
  Log.i(a, "Done");
```

//use String array to show them in Textview or anywhere